# mysql query bulk insert caused sequence gap

Tags: mysql, insert, sequence, auto-increment, bulk

I have a query to `select` and `insert` rows in a table with auto increment col as key.

```
insert into table a select * from table B
```

I found that after executing the query, there is sequence gap in the auto increment column in `table B`

Can it be possible?
Or my select statement failed to insert some records ??

Please help.

I can not repro the case as this is a production server, and I don't have the backup before exec the query.

Many thanks.

Comment: I believe this can happen if you do a roll back while inserting.  ( http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/innodb-auto-increment-handling.html ) "You may see gaps in the sequence of values assigned to the AUTO_INCREMENT column if you roll back transactions that have generated numbers using the counter."

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you are using `InnoDB` with `INSERT IGNORE`, you may want to read this article that talks about this issue:

[Avoiding auto-increment holes on InnoDB with INSERT IGNORE](http://www.mysqlperformanceblog.com/2011/11/29/avoiding-auto-increment-holes-on-innodb-with-insert-ignore/)

### Why do we have gaps?

> InnoDB checks an auto_increment counter on the
>   table and if a new value is needed, increments that counter and
>   assigns the new value to the column. Prior to MySQL 5.1.22 InnoDB used
>   a method to access that counter values called “Traditional“. This one
>   uses a special table lock called AUTO-INC that remains until the end
>   of the query or transaction. Because of this, two queries can’t have
>   the AUTO-INC lock at the same time, so we lose concurrency and
>   performance. The problems are even worse with long running queries
>   like INSERT INTO table1 … SELECT … FROM table2.

When using a simple insert from select, there's a [known bug about this](http://bugs.mysql.com/bug.php?id=61058)

In conclusion, i wouldn't say this is a problem with your query, but more related to the way the engine deals with the insert from select blocks.

Comment: Thanks. my query is just insert without ignore and the query is a batch run, there should not be any other query running at the same time. Sorry, i am quite new in sql.

Comment: There's a [known bug on this](http://bugs.mysql.com/bug.php?id=61058). Do you have multiple `insert from select`?